# RViz segfaults unless a monitor is connected, any way to prevent this?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I connect to my robot running Ubuntu 10.10, Diamondback via VNC.  Everything is fine except RViz.  It gives no output except for "Segmentation Error" unless a monitor is plugged in by VGA.  Beyond this point I can just unplug the monitor and continue to work over VNC.  But it's fairly frustrating.  Anybody got any suggestion as to how to prevent this?  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9743/rviz--segfaults-unless-a-monitor-is-connected,-any-way-to-prevent-this?/) by [splasho](https://answers.ros.org/users/431/splasho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-04-15

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu will not initialize X Windows (the windowing/graphics system) if there is not a monitor at boot.  This means that VNC and remote desktop will not start either (nor network manager, which is a pain sometimes).

So, in order to "fool" your computer into thinking that there is a monitor, get a VGA cable, and make a loopback or dummy connector for when you run headless. Connect pins 1 to 6, 2 to 7, and 3 to 8 using 50-200 ohm resistors (tutorials seem to vary, 200 is on the safe side).

Your new "dummy" will show up as a 1024x768 VGA monitor, good to go.  X windows will now start at boot.

DISCLAIMER: I don't claim that this will work, but other people on the internet do.  Try at your own risk.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-04-28**:
I did try the vga dummy but I get a max resolution of 640x480, the other option was 320x240. How do I get at least 1024x768 resolution?

**Comment by [splasho](https://answers.ros.org/users/431/splasho/) on 2011-04-22**:
This wasn't the case for me - VNC was starting fine, but RViz wasn't.  But thanks for the VGA trick.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you are likely seeing is that, without the VGA connected, your graphics doesn't startup at all. On our robots, without a monitor plugged in on bootup, the discrete graphics cards don't get initialized and X never starts, so VNC with RViz wouldn't work so well.

In either case, VNC or forwarding X is probably not the best way to work with rviz remotely. A much better plan would be to follow the directions on [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) to get your computer connected to the robot's rosmaster (setting the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP for both machines is what I do instead of setting up DNS). This way, you can run rviz locally on your computer, only sending ROS data across the network instead of forwarding X or VNC, both of which I found to be quite slow when working with a 3D application like rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [splasho](https://answers.ros.org/users/431/splasho/) on 2011-04-22**:
Yeah unfortunately for complex reasons my second computer had to be running windows, I agree VNC is slow.  In my case X was starting, it wasn't simply a matter of boot up, regardless of how I booted up RViz would not start without a monitor plugged in.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb is something what helped me on case when I needed dummy graphics.

---

Originally posted by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) with karma: 161 on 2011-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try [virtualgl](http://www.virtualgl.org). It did solve the rviz segfault for me. When your finished setting up just run rviz like this:

```
vglrun rosrun rviz rviz
```

---

Originally posted by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) with karma: 475 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2